# Conflict between livewire image preview and mcamara / laravel-localization

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-livewire, laravel-localization

I am using the livewire image preview temporaryUrl() function

```
<input wire:model="image" type="file" accept="image/*">
<img class="input-img-preview" src="{{$image->temporaryUrl()}}">
```

It is working fine when I do the command:

```
php artisan optimize
```

But the language routes are turning into 404 error!

And when I use this command:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

The language routes are working fine but the image preview crashes.

BTW I am using mcamara/laravel-localization